# Фильтрация в DataGridView через выбор в ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня вот такой проект: [image: dataGridView with some info]

Мне нужно, чтобы comboBox фильтровал dataGridView, например, я выбираю coupe и только 86 и Supra будут отображены.

Также, если я 2 раза кликну по нужной мне модели другое окно откроется [image: All available Camry sets]

Мне нужно, чтобы данные тут тоже фильтровались.

У меня есть 2 класса

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Toyota_beta
{
    public class Models
    {

        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; } 
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }

        public List<Cars> Cars { get; set; }



        public Models(string model, string type, string year, 
        string price, List<Cars> cars)
        {
            Model = model; Year = year; Type = type;
            Price = price; Cars = cars;
        }
        public Models()
        {

            Cars = new List<Cars>();
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Toyota_beta
{
    public class Cars
    {

            public string Model { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public string Transmission { get; set; }
            public string Drive { get; set; }
            public int Hp { get; set; }
            public string Engine { get; set; }
            public int Price { get; set; }


            public Cars(string model, int year, string transmission, string drive, string engine,
            int hp, int price)
            {
                Model = model; Year = year; Transmission = transmission;
                Drive = drive; Hp = hp; Engine = engine; Price = price;
            }
            public Cars()
            { }

    }
}
```

И все данные в dataGridView я вставил вручную

```
namespace Toyota_beta
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<Models> listM = new List<Models>();
        public List<Cars> listC;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Yaris---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            listC = new List<Cars>();
            listC.Add(new Cars("Yaris L", 2020, "Manual", "FWD", "Fuel", 106, 15650));
            listC.Add(new Cars("Yaris XLE", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 106, 18750));

            listM.Add(new Models("Yaris ", "Sedan", "2020", "from 15,650$", listC));

            //Yaris Hatchback---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            listC = new List<Cars>();
            listC.Add(new Cars("Yaris LE Hatchback", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 106, 17750));


            listM.Add(new Models("Yaris Hatchback", "Hatchback", "2020", "from 17,750$", listC));

            //Corolla---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            listC = new List<Cars>();
            listC.Add(new Cars("Corolla L", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 139, 19600));
            listC.Add(new Cars("Corolla LE", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 139, 20050));
            listC.Add(new Cars("Corolla Hybrid LE", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 169, 23100));

            listM.Add(new Models("Cororlla", "Sedan", "2020", "from 19,600$", listC));
...
```

Вот как я заполнил второе dataGridView

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null || dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index == dataGridView1.RowCount - 1)
                return;

            Info formC = new Info();


            int n = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
            formC.carsBindingSource.DataSource = listM[n].Cars;

            formC.ShowDialog();
            modelsBindingSource.ResetCurrentItem();

        }
```

Мб эти скриншоты помогут понять общую ситуацию

Вот что я пробовал сделать сам: создать bool method который отбирает ряды dataGridView, которые надо показывать или нет, но у меня постоянно разные проблемы

```
private void b_Show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool select = false;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                if (TestRow(i))
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                    select = true;
                }
            }

        }
        private bool TestRow(int c)
        {
            Cars crs = Form1.listM[m];

            if (comboBox_type.Text != "" &&
                !crs.Type.Contains(comboBox_type.Text)) return false;





        }
```

Не бейте, если мой код похож на какашку, я только пытаюсь разобраться в c#. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вопрос актуален?

Comment: Да, если есть какие-то еще вопросы о программе, могу добавить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: пример работы]

Работу с данными надо выделять в отдельный класс.

```
public class AppData
{
    private List<Model> _models;

    public AppData()
    {
        var listY = new List<Car>();
        listY.Add(new Car("Yaris L", 2020, "Manual", "FWD", "Fuel", 106, 15650));
        listY.Add(new Car("Yaris XLE", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 106, 18750));

        var listYH = new List<Car>();
        listYH.Add(new Car("Yaris LE Hatchback", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 106, 17750));

        var listC = new List<Car>();
        listC.Add(new Car("Corolla L", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 139, 19600));
        listC.Add(new Car("Corolla LE", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 139, 20050));
        listC.Add(new Car("Corolla Hybrid LE", 2020, "Automatic", "FWD", "Fuel", 169, 23100));
        listC.Add(new Car("Corolla LE", 2018, "Automatic", "AWD", "Fuel", 139, 21500));
        listC.Add(new Car("Corolla", 2019, "Manual", "AWD", "Fuel", 139, 22500));
        listC.Add(new Car("Corolla L", 2017, "Manual", "AWD", "Fuel", 139, 18500));

        _models = new List<Model>
        {
            new Model("Yaris ", "Sedan", "2020", "from 15,650$", listY),
            new Model("Yaris Hatchback", "Hatchback", "2020", "from 17,750$", listYH),
            new Model("Cororlla", "Coupe", "2020", "from 19,600$", listC)
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<Model> GetModels() => _models.AsEnumerable();

    public IEnumerable<string> GetModelsTypes() => _models.Select(m => m.Type);

    public IEnumerable<Model> GetModelsByType(string type) =>
        _models.Where(m => m.Type.Equals(type));

}
```

Тогда и форма становится проще

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    //источник данных для DGV
    private BindingSource _bsModels;
    //данные
    private AppData _appData;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _appData = new AppData();
        _bsModels = new BindingSource();

        //привязки DGV & столбцов
        _dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        _dataGridView.DataSource = _bsModels;
        _columnTitle.DataPropertyName = nameof(Model.Title);
        _columnYear.DataPropertyName = nameof(Model.Year);
        _columnType.DataPropertyName = nameof(Model.Type);
        _columnPrice.DataPropertyName = nameof(Model.Price);

        this.Load += FormMain_Load;
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //заполняем DGV
        _appData.GetModels()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(m => _bsModels.Add(m));

        //заполняем комбобокс
        var types = new List<string> { "Все" };
        types.AddRange(_appData.GetModelsTypes());
        _comboBoxType.DataSource = types;

        //подписка на выбор в комбобксе
        _comboBoxType.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBoxType_SelectedIndexChanged;
        //подписка на 2-й клик в DGV
        _dataGridView.CellDoubleClick += DataGridView_CellDoubleClick;
    }

    private void ComboBoxType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //очищаем DGV
        _bsModels.Clear();

        var type = (sender as ComboBox).Text;
        if (type != "Все")
        {
            //заполняем нужным типом
            _appData.GetModelsByType(type)
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(m => _bsModels.Add(m));
        }
        else
        {
            //извлекаем, заполняем полным списком
            _appData.GetModels()
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(m => _bsModels.Add(m));
        }
    }

    private void DataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //определяем выбранную в DGV модель
        var model = _bsModels.Current as Model;

        //создаем экз.формы с передачей выбранной модели
        var formCars = new FormCars(model);
        formCars.Owner = this;
        formCars.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Весь пример целиком [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/WindowsFormsDGVSearch).

Comment: Хорошо, с этим я разобрался, а не подскажешь, как сделать Уникальным набор в comboBox? Например, если я добавлю еще 1 авто sedan, то и в comboBox'e у меня появится еще 1 вариант, который делает то же самое

Comment: Надо использовать [Distinct()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Понял, а не подскажешь, вот для второй формы я создал comboBox, откуда мне брать данные для сортировки?

Comment: В смысле данные для заполнения комбобокса? В модели, кот. передана через конструктор содержится список машин, из него можно взять данные, или забить заранее через дизайнер.